# How to read a file and get certain lines in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I have a file and it has content like this:

```
abc.com.        IN A            10.10.40.94 ;10.120.40.61    ;10.60.3.135
def.com.            IN CNAME        some-domain.com.

xyz.com.        IN A            10.123.40.32    ;10.145.40.133    ;1.240.3.215
one.com.                IN CNAME        some-other-domain.com.
```

What I want to do is, get all the lines with `IN A` and print them to another file so the final file would look like below:

I tried `awk` as follows:

```
cat dev-mytaxi.com.zone | awk '{print $3}'
```

but how can I write to a file and the final outcome as mentioned below?

final output written to a new file should look like:

```
abc.com 10.10.40.94 10.120.40.61 10.60.3.135
xyz.com 10.123.40.32 10.145.40.133 1.240.3.215
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. special thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do let us know what is the logic of getting sample output too in your question.

Comment: To write to a file you just need `>` : `your command > file` will write the output of your command into a file named `file` in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this simpler `awk` with custom `FS`:

```
awk -F '[.[:blank:]]+IN A[[:blank:]]+' 'NF > 1 {
gsub(/[;[:blank:]]+/, " ", $2); print $1, $2}' file
```

```
abc.com 10.10.40.94 10.120.40.61 10.60.3.135
xyz.com 10.123.40.32 10.145.40.133 1.240.3.215
```

**How it works:**

- Here we are using a regex `[.[:blank:]]+IN A[[:blank:]]+` as input field separator that splits each record by a `IN A` text surrounded by whitespaces on either side.
- `NF > 1` will be true only for lines with `IN A` record
- `gsub` converts multiple spaces and `;` with a single space between ip addresses

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice code, may I ask you if we could add regex tag here since you have written nice regex here, what do you say sir? because as per recommendations also tags should be decided as per answers and question both.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Yes I think we can add that tag as both the answers are using regex based approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/IN A/ { match($1,/^;/);printf "%s %s ",substr($1,RSTART+RLENGTH),$4;for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s ",substr($i,2) } printf "%s","\n" }' ipdat > ipdat1
```

Using the above awk command and wit hthe source data in a file called ipdat, we search for the string "IN A" and then process the line accordingly. We take the 1st and 4th delimited field and print with spaces as separators. We then use awk's substr function to take the 5th, 6th and 7th delimited fields, printing from the second character onward in order to strip the first ";" character. All output is redirected to another file (in this case ipdat1)

Comment: How can I get rid of `;` in front of some domains?

Comment: I've amended the answer to find for a ; prefix in the domain name  and then remove the ; accordingly.

Comment: Thankyou. There is a one problem, I don't want to always use `substr($5,2)` or `substr($6,2)` and `substr($8,2)` because that ips can vary from 1-6 ips. In that case I might need to add `substr($9,2)`, `substr($10,2)` and on... How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Add the additional code to take account of the maximum number of IP addresses. Then those lines with additional IP addresses, will print the additional IP addresses, those without won't

Comment: That is what I `DON'T` want to do

Comment: OK, I've added a for loop

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I said. You have hard coded `5` for the loop. I don't want to hardcore anything other than the file. Because that loop you are using can be changed anytime, sometimes as I mentioned, from 1-6 or 1-20 even

Comment: This is because the 5th delimited piece will always be the first field with an IP address that needs the ";" character removed. The loop will then run from 5 to NF which is the last field in the line.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$,=" "} print /^(\S+?)\.?\s/, /\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/g if /IN A/' ip.txt
abc.com 10.10.40.94 10.120.40.61 10.60.3.135
xyz.com 10.123.40.32 10.145.40.133 1.240.3.215
```

- `$,=" "` sets the separator to be used between multiple arguments/arrays that are passed to `print`
- `if /IN A/` if input line contains `IN A`
- `/^(\S+?)\.?\s/` gets the starting non-whitespace characters, ignores a trailing `.` if present
- `/\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/g` this will get all sequences of 4 numbers separated by `.` character

Comment: What is `perl`  ? a library?

Comment: @JananathJayarathna that's a programming language like `awk` and can be used from command line too