# How to get a string before a specific character in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have some content in the file `lists.txt` as below:

```
abc.com.                IN A        10.120.51.95    ;10.40.40.57 ;old 10.20.3.57    
;def-mytaxi.com.        IN A        10.12.4.9   ;10.40.3.43 ;test
xyz-mytaxi.com.     IN CNAME        10.12.4.8   ;10.40.3.53 ;test
```

So, I need to write these to another file so

1. It should avoid any row starting with `;` - `2nd row is avoided`
2. It should only picks the rows with `IN A` - `only the 1st row is seletced`
3. It should remove the training `.` at the end of every first column - `remove . after abc.com.`
4. It should avoid any values in the selected row/s after ; - `therefore only prints abc.com 10.120.51.95`

and the final output should be written to a file and it should look like;

```
abc.com 10.120.51.95
```

So I wrote this script but everything works fine except the `3rd` and the `4th` steps.

I get the output as:

```
abc.com.   10.120.51.95   10.40.40.57 old 10.20.3.57
```

here's what I tried, can someone help me?

```
awk '/IN A/ {$2=$3=""; print $0}' lists.txt  | sed '/^;/d;s/;//g;s/#//g' > updated_list.txt
```

Comment: Just wondering if this answer on your previous question worked for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553314/548225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are very clear and well defined. So the whole job can be done by an `awk` script:

```
awk '/^;/ || (!/IN A/) {next}          # condition 1 and condition 2
     {sub(/IN A/,"",$0);$1=$1;$0=$0}   # condition 5, FS>OFS, recompute fields
     {sub(/[.]$/,"",$1)}               # condition 3
     {sub(/;.*$/,"",$0)}               # condition 4
     {sub(/[.]$/,"",$NF)}              # condition 6 (IP is now in last col)
     { print }' file
```

- Condition 1 to 4 are given by the OP.
- Condition 5 wants to remove `IN A`
- Condition 6 remove potential final `.` from IP

Comment: Works fine but I need to get rid of `IN A` part as well. this output gives everything good but it has `IN A`

Comment: @JananathJayarathna is your file tab-delimited, space delimited or unknown?

Comment: Unknown and, some IP's have an extra `.` at the end, how can I get rid of those as well like we did for the first column?

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should also work:

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*;/ && / IN A / {
   sub(/\.$/, "", $1)
   print $1, $4
}' file
```

```
abc.com 10.120.51.95
```

Comment: This doesn't only remove the lines starting with `;` but also the lines that has `;` in the middle as well

Comment: @JananathJayarathna For testing, please post such lines that fail. Don't post them as comments or images, please edit them to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @JananathJayarathna: Output in my answer is same as what you expected right?

Comment: Also you can try my updated answer. btw post all inputs with expected output in question and accept an answer only after checking it generates your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
!/^;/ && /IN A/{
  sub(/\.+$/,"",$1)
  match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +;/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +;.*/,"",val)
  print $1,val
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
!/^;/ && /IN A/{                       ##Checking condition if line DO NOT start from ; AND has IN A in it then do following.
  sub(/\.+$/,"",$1)                    ##Substituting all dots trailing in first field with NULL here.
  match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +;/)   ##Using match by mentioning regex to match IP address followed by space and followed by semi colon in here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)        ##Creating val variable which has sub string of matched regex in above statement.
  sub(/ +;.*/,"",val)                  ##Substituting all spaces and everything from semi colon to last of line in val here.
  print $1,val                         ##Printing first field and val here.
  val=""                               ##Nullifying val here.
}' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @JananathJayarathna, its working fine for me and tested well, please do let me know if you copied it correctly?

Comment: Syntax is gone, but this doesn't print the IP address/s

Comment: @JananathJayarathna, sorry I didn't get it, you are saying syntax is wrong? I have tested it with shown samples and it worked fine for me, what error are you getting please post in here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hmm, confirmed. It fails to print the ip on mawk, Interesting. And awk version 20121220 so it probably fails in MacOS too.

Comment: @JamesBrown, for me in GNU `awk` it works may be its regex, let me add 1 more now.

Comment: @JananathJayarathna, could you please check now I have changed the regex part, let me know?

Comment: @JamesBrown, Thanks for confirming, that's why I mention I tested it on GNU `awk` :) could you please let me know if this works now, I don't have mawk with me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'match($1,/^[^;].*/)&&$2=="IN"&&$3=="A"{print substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),$4}' file
```

Output:

```
abc.com 10.120.51.95
```

"Explained":

```
$ awk '
match($1,/^[^;].*/) && $2=="IN" && $3=="A" {     # match 
    print substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),$4         # and output
}' file
```

**Edit**: To remove the trailing . from the ip:

```
awk '
match($1,/^[^;].*/) && $2=="IN" && $3=="A" {
    print substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),
        ($4~/\.$/?substr($4,1,length($4)-1):$4)  # remove extra . from ip
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/^[a-z].*IN A/{sub(/\.$/, "", $1); print $1, $4}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
awk '{ gsub(/;.*/,"")} / IN A / { gsub(/\.$/,"",$1); printf("%s %s\n",$1,$4)}' FILE
```